# jquery slim behaving weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to run this with ***jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js***

```
$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("click"); });             
$("span").click(function(event){
  $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

but it did not work with this version 
but when i tried to use ***jquery-3.3.1.min.js*** it worked correctly
so is the problem in my code or in jquery ?

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: `.fadeOut` is removed as well as all other `animation`s in favor of CSS3 native animation and transition.

Comment: Look in your browser dev tools console. Should see `fadeOut is not a function`. Should always look in there when code doesn't work